# map.join function error: returns a list of letters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two lists of lists, however, when map/join functions are implemented, they returned different results. The first one is the result that I desire.

```
list1 = ['I woke up at 6am today.',
     'I live in vancouver.',
     'I go to gym by 6pm.',]

list2 =`[['7am run \u200d♂️ done ✅ @kristianevofit @ottowallin @trboxing @btsport @ringtv @frank_warren_official @mtkglobal @marbella.co.uk'],
```

['I have succummed to the #bottlecapchallenge ⛑ What do you think? #bluesteel #scrubs']]`

The function:

`[''.join(x) for x in list1]
[''.join(x) for x in list2]`

Result for list1:

```
['I woke up at 6am today.',
 'I live in vancouver.',
 'I go to gym by 6pm.',]
```

Result for `list2`:

```
['[',
 '[',
 "'",
 '7',

 'a',
 'm',
 ' ',
 'r',
 'u',]']
```

The desired result is to produce the same result on `list2` as on `list1`.

I am very grateful to your help!!

Comment: your `List2` is not list. It is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list2` is a list of list in `string` while your `list1` is a list of string. Hence, you would need to flatten your `list2` in order to get result like `list1` as below.

```
import ast

# Convert to list
list2 = ast.literal_eval(list2)

# Flatten nested list/list of list into list
flat_list2 = [y for x in list2 for y in x]

# Then you can use this
result = [''.join(x) for x in List2]
```

Alternatively, you can combine them:

```
import ast

list2 = ast.literal_eval(list2)
result [''.join(y) for x in list2 for y in x]
```

Of course, you'll need to ensure your string of nested list have to follow correct python syntax. Below is the code running in `IPython`

```
In [1]: list2 = """[[\'7am run \\u200d♂️ done ✅ @kristianevofit @ottowallin @trboxing @btsport @ringtv @frank_warren_official @mtkglobal @marbella.co.uk\'],   
   ...: [\'I have succummed to the #bottlecapchallenge ⛑ What do you think? #bluesteel #scrubs\']]"""                                                                                                          

In [2]: import ast                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: list2 = ast.literal_eval(list2)                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: result = [''.join(y) for x in list2 for y in x]                                                                                                                                                            

In [5]: result                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[5]: 
['7am run \u200d♂️ done ✅ @kristianevofit @ottowallin @trboxing @btsport @ringtv @frank_warren_official @mtkglobal @marbella.co.uk',
 'I have succummed to the #bottlecapchallenge ⛑ What do you think? #bluesteel #scrubs']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I run the code, it raised an error of " malformed node or string'. Do you know how to solve it? Sincerely.

Comment: I believe you should correct your input first, I'll make an edit showing that my code works on corrected `list2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) This will be useful for you:

```
import ast 
list2 = ast.literal_eval(list2)
result2 = [''.join(x) for x in List2]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I run the code, it raised an error of " malformed node or string'. Do you know how to solve it? Sincerely.

Comment: Can you check that the value of list2, because I am getting an error:                                                                                                       
     File "<ipython-input-3-772a860f0479>", line 1
    x =  ` [['7am run \u200d♂️ done ✅ @kristianevofit @ottowallin @trboxing @btsport @ringtv @frank_warren_official @mtkglobal @marbella.co.uk'],['I have succummed to the #bottlecapchallenge ⛑ What do you think? #bluesteel #scrubs']] `
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .     Are backticks present in a string or not?